# LLVM ERROR: Error parsing inline asm, unexpected token

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am new to LLVM and clang. I am working on a tool that uses LLVM/clang in the backend as a compiler. With the recent changes in LLVM tool, I have started getting following error:

```
<inline asm>:1:13: error: unexpected token in argument list
        lock addb 2$2, 1048576
                   ^
LLVM ERROR: Error parsing inline asm
```

I do not have any idea how to resolve this. Any input is appreciated.